# C++ - Checking struct string data with user entered string data (infinite do while loop)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct

As you can see from the title I want to "compare" string entered by user with the string read from the file.
I have used struct data type to read data from files.

Here is the input file

```
Samed Skulj Stomatolog
Adin Vrbic Hirurg
Ahmed Skulj Psihijatar
```

Before we go to the problem here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct dataAboutDoctors
{
    string name;
    string surname;
    string profession;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    ifstream readingDoctors;
    readingDoctors.open("citanjedoktora.txt");
    if (readingDoctors.fail())
    {
        cout << "Ne postojeca datoteka";
        exit(1);
    }
    
    dataAboutDoctors doctors[100];
    int numbersOfDoctors = 0;
    
    while(readingDoctors >> doctors[numbersOfDoctors].name >> doctors[numbersOfDoctors].surname >> doctors[numbersOfDoctors].profession)
    {
        numbersOfDoctors++;
    }
    cout << "----- Name of doctors and their professions -----" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    string temp1,temp2;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersOfDoctors; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name of " << i+1 <<". doctor: " << doctors[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Surname of " << i+1 <<". doctor: " << doctors[i].surname << endl;
        cout << "Profession of " << i+1 <<". doctor: " << doctors[i].profession << endl;
        cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
        temp1+=doctors[i].name;
        temp2+=doctors[i].surname;
        cout << endl;
    }
    string name1,surname1;
    cout << "Enter the name of doctor you see: ";
    cin >> name1;
    cout << "Enter the surname of doctor you see: ";
    cin >> surname1;
    do
    {
    if (name1 != temp1 || surname1 != temp2)
    {
        cout << "There is no name nor surname of the doctor you have entered. Enter again: ";
        cin >> name1 >> surname1;
    }
    }while(name1 != temp1 || surname1 != temp2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

When user enter the name of the doctor and the surname and if it is the CORRECT name and surname the program should continue doing other stuff but in this case or example you cant see the other part of the program beacuse it is not as important.

Here is the console input

```
----- Name of doctors and their professions -----
---------------------------------------------
Name of 1. doctor: Samed
Surname of 1. doctor: Skulj
Profession of 1. doctor: Stomatolog
------------------------------------------

Name of 2. doctor: Adin
Surname of 2. doctor: Vrbic
Profession of 2. doctor: Hirurg
------------------------------------------

Name of 3. doctor: Ahmed
Surname of 3. doctor: Skulj
Profession of 3. doctor: Psihijatar
------------------------------------------

Enter the name of doctor you see:
```

`Enter the name of doctor you see:` this is the main problem. When user enters even the right name it again ask the user to enter the name and surname and again, and again
So as you can see I have managed to make infinite loop.

My question is how to so-called "compare" the user entered string and the string read from the .txt file?

Comment: @ Samed Škulj The loop does not make sense. How can these variables         temp1+=doctors[i].name;
        temp2+=doctors[i].surname;  be equal to a single name or surname?!

Comment: Try a `cout << temp1 << endl;` before the last loop to see why it's not working this way. You have a list of all doctors' information in `doctors` already - use that, instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop

```
string temp1,temp2;
for (int i = 0; i < numbersOfDoctors; i++)
{
    // ...
    temp1+=doctors[i].name;
    temp2+=doctors[i].surname;
}
```

you are accumulating names and surnames in one string even without embedded spaces.

So this loop

```
do
{
if (name1 != temp1 || surname1 != temp2)
{
    cout << "There is no name nor surname of the doctor you have entered. Enter again: ";
    cin >> name1 >> surname1;
}
}while(name1 != temp1 || surname1 != temp2);
```

will never interrupt its iterations until you enter a string that will contain all names and surname in single strings.

Maybe you need to change the condition in the if statement and in the loop to

```
( temp1.find( name1 ) == std::string::npos || temp2.find( surname1 ) == std::string::npos )
```

And logically relative to the used condition in the if statement the message should look like

```
"There is no name or surname of the doctor you have entered. Enter again: "
                 ^^^
```

In fact using the variables `temp1` and `temp2` does not make sense. You should remove them. This part of the program can look the following way

```
#include <algorithm> // this header is required for using std::find_if

//...

string name1,surname1;
cout << "Enter the name of doctor you see: ";
cin >> name1;
cout << "Enter the surname of doctor you see: ";
cin >> surname1;

bool success = false;
do
{
    success = std::find_if( doctors, doctors + numbersOfDoctors,
                            [&]( const auto &d )
                            {
                                return d.name == name1 && d.surname == surname1;
                            } ) != doctors + numbersOfDoctors;

    if ( not success )
    {
        cout << "There is no name or surname of the doctor you have entered. Enter again: ";
        cin >> name1 >> surname1;
    }
} while( not success );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct dataAboutDoctors
{
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    std::string profession;
};

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    dataAboutDoctors doctors[N] =
    {
        { "Samed", "Skulj", "Stomatolog" },
        { "Adin",  "Vrbic", "Hirurg" },
        { "Ahmed", "Skulj", "Psihijatar" }  
    };

    size_t numbersOfDoctors = 3;

    std::string name1, surname1;

    std::cout << "Enter the name of doctor you see: ";
    std::cin >> name1;
    std::cout << "Enter the surname of doctor you see: ";
    std::cin >> surname1;

    bool success = false;
    do
    {
        success = std::find_if( doctors, doctors + numbersOfDoctors,
                            [&]( const auto &d )
                            {
                                return d.name == name1 && d.surname == surname1;
                            } ) != doctors + numbersOfDoctors;

        if ( not success )
        {
            std::cout << "There is no name or surname of the doctor you have entered. Enter again: ";
            std::cin >> name1 >> surname1;
        }   
    } while( not success ); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I copied this part of the program from you but it ends up not compiling at all

Comment: @SamedŠkulj I appended my answer with a demonstrative program that compiles successfully.